What is an upper bound for the maximum consecutive spacing between two elements of a 2-cyclotomic coset mod $n$?
Suppose I have a 2-cyclotomic coset mod $n$, consisting of $k$ elements i.e.
\begin{equation}
C_s = \{s\cdot 2^x \;\text{mod} \;n \mid x\in [k]\}.
\end{equation}
What is a good tight upper bound for the maximum spacing between two consecutive elements? For example, $C_7$ mod 15 is $\{7,11,13,14\}$, so the max spacing is 4. I have tried a few crude bounds but in the case of $n\to\infty$ they all reduce to $\frac{\text{spacing}}{n}\leq \frac{1}{2}$ which is trivial.

Modulo $15$ we have $C_5={5,10}$ with a maximum gap of five.

I now see that you have an unexpected parameter $k$. Are you not necessarily considering full cyclotomic cosets, or what is the role it plays?

$k$ simply means that we know the cyclotomic coset contains $k$ elements (so $k \mid \text{ord}_n(2)$), but we haven't calculated the specific elements yet and want to know a priori what a spacing bound would be as $n\to\infty$ and $k\to\infty$.

Ok so what I think this problem could be reformulated as is, can you achieve asymptotic good parameters for a cyclic code with generator $g(x)=(x^n-1)/(m(x))$, where $m(x)$ is a minimal polynomial associated with some cyclotomic coset $C_s$, i.e. $m(x) = \prod_{i\in C_s}(x-\beta^i)$ for a root of unity $\beta$.

There's no bound better than $(\frac12-\varepsilon)n$ in general. One family of witnesses is $\{1,2,2^2,\dots,2^k\}$ modulo $2^{k+1}-1$. (Here I'm counting the “wraparound gap” from $2^k$ to $1\equiv 2^{k+1}$ as well. If that gap doesn't count, I suspect $\frac12$ is still the best one can do asymptotically, but we'd need a slightly cleverer construction.)

A construction giving the highest gaps I can think of is the following. Posting it to get things rolling.
Assume that $3\mid n$. Let $m=n/3$. It follows that the cyclotomic coset
$$
C_m=\{m,2m\}.
$$
This is because $4m\equiv m\pmod n$.
With this cyclotomic coset the largest gap is $n/3$. If we, following Greg Martin, allow wraparound gaps, then the wraparound gap from $2n/3$ to $n/3\equiv4n/3$ is $(2/3)n$.

I obtained this same result as well, as I was looking for cosets with the maximum number of elements w.r.t. $n$ (if $n$ is prime) and the max spacing (the one you mentioned). What I want to analyse is whether they can both be big w.r.t $n$, i.e. if $|C_s|/n\to \rho>0$ as $n\to\infty$, can $\text{spacing}/n\to\delta > 0$ or vice versa. I know there is a theorem that says that cyclic codes ${C_i}$ can only be asymptotically good if their length $n_i$ has prime factors from a set of primes of size $\infty$, and that it is related, however I see no continuation to prove anything concrete.
